# Checking CRS of project layers against reference one

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have a lot of layers in my project. I need to compare coordinate reference system (CRS) of these layers with another layer used as a reference layer.

I wrote a script to do it, but it didn't work like I thought it would.

```
mapcanvas  = iface.mapCanvas()
layers = mapcanvas.layers()

for l in layers:
    #print l.name()
    print l.crs().authid() #printando o epsg
    if l.crs().authid() == "ESPG:31983": #here I would check SRC
        print 'ok'
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: You can use 'postgisSrid' method (it produces an integer number) instead of 'authid'.

Comment: I found out your initial error. You should use `if l.crs().authid() == "EPSG:31983"`; not `if l.crs().authid() == "ESPG:31983"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out:

```
mapcanvas  = iface.mapCanvas()
layers = mapcanvas.layers()

for l in layers:
    #print l.name()
    print l.crs().authid() #printando o epsg
    if l.crs().postgisSrid() == 31983: #here I would check SRC
        print 'ok'
    else:
        pass
```

It works for me.

**Editing Note**

The error in your original code is only in **if** line. Next one works fine.

```
mapcanvas  = iface.mapCanvas()
layers = mapcanvas.layers()

for l in layers:
    #print l.name()
    print l.crs().authid() #printando o epsg
    if l.crs().authid() == "EPSG:31983": #It is EPSG; not ESPG
        print 'ok'
    else:
        pass
```